# Publish vstest results to TFS with credentials

Tags: c#, powershell, tfs, ui-testing

### Problem description

We're using TFS on a remote server to manage work items, code and builds. Every night all of our code gets built and unit tests are run. However, there are also a few (SpecFlow) UI tests we want to run, but they depend on services that are in the local network at the office. As such, those tests cannot be run on the build server. Due to network restrictions we cannot run a test agent or controller in the office that connects to the build server.

Our current solution is to schedule a script every night, that runs after the nightly build has completed. This script gets the latest sources, runs the tests and publishes the results to the build.

The problem is that while most of these commands support a command line parameter for supplying credentials (for instance, **tf.exe** does), **vstest.exe** does not.

When I run this script interactively in a command prompt, the script runs fine until it reaches the vstest.exe call. Because of the **/logger:tfspublisher** parameter, it asks for credentials to the TFS server. The second time I run the script in the same command prompt it does not ask and apparently uses saved credentials.

When this script runs as a scheduled task, it of course cannot ask for credentials so the test result publishing fails.

### Things I've tried

1. Use **runas /netonly /user:TFSUser**. This would be great except I cannot supply a password, nor can I pipe it in.
2. Use [CPAU](http://www.joeware.net/freetools/tools/cpau/) to call the program. For some reason it still asks for credentials. This is the command I used: **cpau.exe -u user -p password -wait -nowarn -ex runtests.bat**
3. Use [CredMan.ps1](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-Credentials-d44c3cde) to create the credentials beforehand. I checked which credentials were created when I manually entered them (a GENERIC one and a DOMAIN_PASSWORD one), then created them with the script. It *still* asks for credentials, so they must be stored elsewhere.

### Next steps

What I (think I) need is a way to publish the test results to the TFS server which allows me to supply credentials on the command prompt.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you try to run the command with the credential you need?

Comment: Do you mean "run as a different user"? I can't do that since the TFS server is in another domain and another town, so it won't recognise the domain\user that I enter.

Comment: I would question the validity of your speckflow tests if they depend on an external system...

Comment: I'm trying to solve this same issue without success. In my case I'm using VSTS instead and when I run the command the microsoft account login window gets open. The only way I found to make it work is to keep the build machine with the microsoft account signed in.